# Como pegar valor de um input e manipular no behind

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

Galera to com uma dificuldade onde eu preciso pegar o valor de um input do tipo text e manipular ele no cs da página aspx. Estou usando `repeater` para adicionar os dados a tabela, mas ao tentar puxar os dados do input não estou obtendo sucesso...

pagina.aspx:

```
 <input type="text" id="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" />
```

pagina.aspx.cs:

```
namespace GerencialWeb
{
    public partial class ReceitasPeriodicas : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        public class Fluxo
        {
            public DateTime data { get; set; }
            public double valor { get; set; }

        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            double valort = Request["dinheiro"];


            List<Fluxo> ListaFluxo = new List<Fluxo>();            
            ListaFluxo.Add(new Fluxo() { valor = variavel do request  ,data = DateTime.Now });




            this.rptFluxo.DataSource = ListaFluxo;
            this.rptFluxo.DataBind();


        }        
    }
}
```

Obs: O valor que entra no input tem uma função que o transforma em valor (Moeda): Uma mask em js. (Mesmo o valor puro sem mask, já foi testado e também sem sucesso.). alguém tem alguma ideia do que fazer?

Comment: coloque o que fez na página!

Comment: Editei lá a página do .cs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que você só precisa colocar um `runat="server"` na sua input:

```
<input type="text" id="dinheiro" name="dinheiro" runat="server"/>
```

E assim, poderá obter o conteúdo do controle por aqui:

```
string myStringFromTheInput = dinheiro.Value;
```

E assim portanto:

```
public partial class ReceitasPeriodicas : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public class Fluxo
    {
        public DateTime data { get; set; }
        public double valor { get; set; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string myStringFromTheInput = dinheiro.Value;
        double valort = double.Parse(myStringFromTheInput);

        List<Fluxo> ListaFluxo = new List<Fluxo>();            
        ListaFluxo.Add(new Fluxo() { valor = valort, data = DateTime.Now });

        this.rptFluxo.DataSource = ListaFluxo;
        this.rptFluxo.DataBind();
    }        
}
```